# How to serial print "Entry" everytime sensor senses the object entry

Tags: arduino, embedded, sensors

I want to print "Entry" in the serial monitor every-time the sensor senses the object ,but my output is "Entry" " Entry" and so on until unless next entry is sensed and it continues in this format.I want to print "Entry " only when an entry of object is sensed.

```
`

#define trig1 11
#define echo1 10
#define trig2 9
#define echo2 6
#define ledpin 13
int sensor_1 = 0;
int sensor_2 = 0;
int count = 0;
long duration1, distance1;
long duration2, distance2;

//unsigned long prevmillis=0;
//const long interval=1000;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(trig1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trig2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo2, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  //unsigned long prevmillis=millis();

  sensor1(); ///set sensor_1=1
  sensor2();///set sensor_2=1
  if (sensor_1 == 1)
  { if (sensor_2 == 1) {
      Serial.println("Entry");

    }
  }


}

int sensor1(void)
{
  digitalWrite(trig1, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig1, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(echo1, HIGH);

  analogWrite(ledpin, 0);
  distance1 = duration1 * .034 / 2;
  if (distance1 < 10) {
    delay(100);
    sensor_1 = 1;

    //delay(400);

    //count++;
    //unsigned long currentmillis=millis();

    //Serial.println(currentmillis-prevmillis);
    //Serial.println("Sensor1 Sensed Object");
    //Serial.println(count);
    analogWrite(ledpin, 255);
    delay(200);

  }

  //return sensor_1;
}
int sensor2(void)
{
  digitalWrite(trig2, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig2, LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(echo2, HIGH);

  analogWrite(ledpin, 0);
  distance2 = duration2 * .034 / 2;
  if (distance2 < 15) {
    delay(100);
    sensor_2 = 1;

    //delay(400);

    //count++;
    //unsigned long currentmillis=millis();

    //Serial.println(currentmillis-prevmillis);
    //Serial.println("Sensor2 Sensed Object");
    //Serial.println(count);
    analogWrite(ledpin, 255);
    delay(100);

  }
  //return sensor_2;
}
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You does not clear sensor conditional values after usage.

```
if (sensor_1 == 1)
{ 
  if (sensor_2 == 1) 
  {
    Serial.println("Entry");
    sensor_1 = 0;
    sensor_2 = 0;
  }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but i changed the logic to sense the entry and exit.Thanks Again